# Apache Flink and Apache Pulsar

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, apache-pulsar

I am using Flink to read data from Apache Pulsar.
I have a partitioned topic in pulsar with 8 partitions.
I produced 1000 messages in this topic, distributed across the 8 partitions.
I have 8 cores in my laptop, so I have 8 sub-tasks (by default parallelism = # of cores).
I opened the Flink-UI after executing the code from Eclipse, I found that some sub-tasks are not receiving any records (idle).
I am expecting that all the 8 sub-tasks will be utilized (I am expecting that each sub-task will be mapped to one partition in my topic).

After restarting the job, I found that some times 3 sub-takes are utilized and some times 4 tasks are utilized while the remaining sub-tasks kept idle.

please your support to clarify this scenario.

Also how can I know that there is a shuffle between sub-takes or not?

My Code:

```
ConsumerConfigurationData<String> consumerConfigurationData = new ConsumerConfigurationData<>();

Set<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<>();
topicsSet.add("flink-08");

consumerConfigurationData.setTopicNames(topicsSet);
consumerConfigurationData.setSubscriptionName("my-sub0111");
consumerConfigurationData.setSubscriptionType(SubscriptionType.Key_Shared);
consumerConfigurationData.setConsumerName("consumer-01");
consumerConfigurationData.setSubscriptionInitialPosition(SubscriptionInitialPosition.Earliest);

PulsarSourceBuilder<String> builder = PulsarSourceBuilder.builder(new SimpleStringSchema()).pulsarAllConsumerConf(consumerConfigurationData).serviceUrl("pulsar://localhost:6650");

SourceFunction<String> src = builder.build();
DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(src);

stream.print(" >>> ");
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Pulsar question, I don't know enough to help. I recommend setting up a larger test and see how that turns out. Usually, you'd have more partitions than slots and have some slots consume several partitions in a somewhat random fashion.

> Also how can I know that there is a shuffle between sub-takes or not?

The easiest way is to look at the topology of the Flink Web UI. There you should see the number of tasks and the channel types. You could post a screenshot if you want more details but in this case, there is nothing that will be shuffled, since you only have a source and a sink.